# Joining 10-2awg to 12-2awg wire

Tags: electrical

I have a 30 amp breaker with a 10/2 feeding a 220 volt dryer outlet. Currently it is powering an air compresser in the garage. I want to put in a 220 wall switch so I don't have to go to the panel and turn on the breaker to power the compresser.

Can I use 12/2 from the 10/2 to switch and back to the compressor outlet?

Comment: First and foremost! 10/2 is not, and never was, legal to use for a 120/240V electric dryer circuit. An electric dryer requires a neutral along with the 240V feed. 10/2 would be just two hots and a ground if used for 240V. ........Secondly, doesn't the compressor have a switch right on it?

Answer (score 6):

No.  12 AWG wire is only rated for 20 amperes, and so cannot be protected by a 30 ampere breaker.

The switch also has to be rated 30 amperes. Which should solve your problem, as the 30 amp switch should accept the larger wire.

Comment: In addition, you need to make sure the switch is rated for 30 amps.

Answer (score 1):

NO. Use #10 wire and a 30 amp 2-pole switch.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other's said, no.

This is because the switch will carry the load so it and the wire have to be sized accordingly.

[image]